# Alguien sabe por que salen esos errores en el editor?

Tags: javascript, brackets

Estoy empezando a trabajar con javascript..pero al momento de guardar el código me aparecen esos errores, la verdad si ejecuta la aplicación, me sale el error que la variable aun no se esta usando, se que no es un error de sintaxis, pero la verdad es un poco incomodo trabajar asi..ayuda por favor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fernando, bienvenido a SOe. Por recomendacion general, porfavor has el [tour]. Creo que estas reaccionando demasiado a algo muy pequeño. Si tu script funciona, esta bien. No dependas tanto de los supereditores o IDES. No hay nada de malo en tu script.

Comment: Hola @Fernando, lo primero, bienvenido al sitio. Te recomiendo nunca poner código en forma de imagen y ponerlo en modo código (puedes utilizar Cntrl+M para formatearlo a tu gusto). Por otro lado, muchos IDEs detectan código sin usar, código repetido, etc, etc... Vienen bien para detectar errores o limpiar código que te sobra, reestructuración, etc... pero a veces pueden ser molestos dichos errores como es tu caso. En este caso entiendo que es porque no estás utilizando la variable x en ningún sitio, si no que simplemente la estás inicializando. Prueba a poner un `alert(x)` justo debajo.

Comment: @KennyBarrera Gracias amigo. pero no sabre cuando existe un error de sintaxis. soy nuevo.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero muchas gracias lo tome en cuenta, pero a lo mejor otro editor que no marque este tipo de supuestos errores? o si hay como hacerlo en el mismo

Comment: @Fernando Entonces eso debería ser otra pregunta preguntando como eliminar los errores de ese IDE concreto. Yo la verdad que no uso ningún IDE para trabajar con Javascript. Utilizo Sublime Text que es un editor de texto pero que te permite un montón de funciones.

Comment: No sé si está relacionado con esos errores pero puedes probar cambiando la show_errors_inline a false. https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-turn-off-the-red-error-boxes-shown-inline-in-code-when-building/23736/2

Comment: El error puede ser porque usas comillas dobles en lugar de simples, si JShint está así configurado te puede marcar que el uso de dobles está desaconsejado... pero si no nos dices el error que te aparece es complicado